# Electric fields problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

Why is this the case..

[image]

I would have thought it would have followed the E field?

Comment: Just remember:  "electrons swim upstream"

Comment: after which, they are inevitably all eaten by bears

Comment: @Jim I should flag that comment for being funny :P On topic though: take a look at the [Lorentz force wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) and keep in mind that the charge $q = -e$ of an electron is negative. Edit: I see that I completely missed the fact that there was already a good answer to your question. You might want to accept that answer if it cleared up your confusion. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An electric field, or rather, electric field lines radiate from positive charges and flow into negative charges. We all know that opposite charges attract, thus, for a fixed positive charge to attract a negative charge, the negative charge must be compelled to move in the opposite direction of the electric field lines. This is the convention we use. Based on that, it is not hard to see that the electron would accelerate leftward - against the direction of the electric field.

Comment: Ahh.. E-field goes from positive to negative and since E = -q, it would do the opposite..  Stupid me..
Thank you :D